# What is requestScope equivalent in Thymeleaf to use flash messages?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

In typical Spring JSP application I have a controller method like:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@Valid Customer customer, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("customer", customer);
        return "customer/create";
    }
    customerRepository.save(customer);
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("id", customer.getId());
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flash.message", "customer.created");
    return "redirect:/customer/{id}";
}
```

Note the redirectAttributes to set a the `flash.message`.
In JSP I would use:

```
<c:if test="${not empty requestScope['flash.message']}">
    ${requestScope['flash.message']}
</c:if>
```

How would I implement this with Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked:

```
${#vars['flash.message']}
```